# Eclipse Helios support for WAS 6.1

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I am trying to deploy my java web project to websphere application server v6.1 using Eclipse.

But I don't see any Websphere6.1 server in Eclipse - Sever view. I see till websphere 6.0.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Regrettably, there is no support for WebSphere 6.1 under Eclipse. As you noted, WebSphere 6.0 was supported, and now WebSphere [7](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v70-developer-tools-eclipse-36-only), [8](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v80-developer-tools-eclipse-36-only), and [8.5](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v85-developer-tools-beta-1) are supported, but 6.1 was not (except in the IBM-branded version of Eclipse, Rational Application Developer).

Comment: hmm.surprisingly my Eclipse3.6 (Helios) doesn't show the Websphere 7 or 8

Comment: You have to add 7 & 8 support separately via the links I posted.