# Websphere 6.1 plugin for eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, websphere-6.1

I'm trying realy hard to find Websphere 6.1 plugin for eclipse juno.

I didnt find anything in IBM site.

(I want to install STS ide . I understand that this ide is based on eclipse juno).

i would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Regrettably, There is no support in WAS 6.1 in any eclipse version (besides ibm version).

[Eclipse Helios support for WAS 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015224/eclipse-helios-support-for-was-6-1)